# Make write() work like print() in Python turtle graphics?

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

How to fix my Python code to work in turtle graphics window?  Below, I have my Python code. By itself, the code will display a multiplication chart when executed. I need this to work in Turtle Graphics.  I have tried changing `print()` to `turtle.write()` and imported turtle.  I do not know what else I need to do. Please help.

```
import turtle

turtle.write("      Multiplication Table")


# Display numbers
turtle.write("   ", end = '')
for j in range(1, 10):
    turtle.write(" ", j, end = '')

turtle.write() 
turtle.write("--------------------------------")

# Display body of table
for i in range(1, 10):
    turtle.write(i, "|", end = '')
    for j in range(1, 10): 
        # Display the product and align properly
        turtle.write(format(i * j, '3d'), end = '')
    turtle.write()
```

Comment: Why do you expect `turtle.write` to work exactly the same as `print`? It does something rather different (writing text at the location of the turtle, rather than writing a line of output to the console). If you're going to `write` many times, you'll need to move the turtle around to get the different pieces in the right places.

Answer (score 0):

When using `turtle.write()` as a replacement for `print()`, it's able to meet us halfway.  In the horizontal direction, `write()` will keep track of where it is for us, like `print()`, if we specify the `move=True` option.  We need to handle the vertical direction ourselves, using the current font size to move the correct amount:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen

FONT_SIZE = 18
FONT = ('Courier', FONT_SIZE, 'normal')

# Based on number of characters to draw, field width, font aspect ratio, etc.
TABLE_EDGE_ESTIMATE = - ((0.6 * FONT_SIZE) * (11 * 3)) / 2

screen = Screen()
HEIGHT = screen.window_height()/2

turtle = Turtle(visible=False)
turtle.penup()

turtle.goto(0, HEIGHT * 0.9)
turtle.write("Multiplication Table", align="center", font=FONT)

# Display numbers along top
turtle.goto(TABLE_EDGE_ESTIMATE, turtle.ycor() - 2 * FONT_SIZE)
turtle.write("   " * 2, move=True, font=FONT)
for j in range(1, 10):
    turtle.write(format(j, "^3"), move=True, font=FONT)

turtle.goto(TABLE_EDGE_ESTIMATE, turtle.ycor() - FONT_SIZE)
turtle.write("---" * 11, font=FONT)

# Display body of table
turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - FONT_SIZE)

for i in range(1, 10):
    turtle.setx(TABLE_EDGE_ESTIMATE)
    turtle.write(format(i, "^3"), move=True, font=FONT)
    turtle.write(" | ", move=True, font=FONT)

    for j in range(1, 10):
        # Display the product and align properly
        turtle.write(format(i * j, "^3"), move=True, font=FONT)

    turtle.sety(turtle.ycor() - FONT_SIZE)

screen.mainloop()
```

[image]